# Why is this prototype failing?

Tags: javascript

```
function _(e) {
    if (typeof e == 'string') {
        if (e.charAt(0) == '#') {
            return document.getElementById(e.slice(1));
        } else if (e.charAt(0) == '.') {
                var c = document.getElementsByClassName(e.slice(1));
            return (c.length==1)?c[0]:c;
        } else {
                var t = document.getElementsByTagName(e);
            return (t.length==1)?t[0]:t;
        }
    } else {
    console.log('Error. Not a valid string in _.');
    }
}

_.prototype.hide = function() {
//testing 
console.log(this)
}
```

The function works fine, but when i try to add the method hide and try and call it like `_('#menu').hide();`, it throws the error: `TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'hide'` What have I misunderstood?

And yes, I did google this problem, I just don't get it. A hint would be much appreciated.

Comment: It looks to me like you are trying to call hide on the return value of the _ function. I would expect: var x = new _('#menu'); x.hide(); to work, but I don't think that is what you are trying. Maybe you should be returning an object to call hide on from the function.

Comment: must set `return` in `hide()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a constructor function as a regular function, so it won't create an object, it will just return what you specified.

You can use it as a regular function, but then you need to call itself as a constructor to create the object to return, and handle when it's used as a constructor:

```
function _(e) {
  if (!this instanceof _) {
    if (typeof e == 'string') {
      if (e.charAt(0) == '#') {
        return new _(document.getElementById(e.slice(1)));
      } else if (e.charAt(0) == '.') {
        var c = document.getElementsByClassName(e.slice(1));
        return new _((c.length==1)?c[0]:c);
      } else {
        var t = document.getElementsByTagName(e);
        return new _((t.length==1)?t[0]:t);
      }
    } else {
      console.log('Error. Not a valid string in _.');
    }
  } else {
    this.elements = e;
  }
}
```

You might consider to always use an array for the elements, even when it's a single element. Right now the `elements` property will either be an element or an array of elements, so you have to check for this every time you use it...

Comment: what about `hide()`; you havn't mentioned

Comment: thanks, this works only it ruined the simplicity of the first function a bit, since it doesn't return the element directly

Comment: @wije: If you want to return the element directly, then you would have to add your `hide` method to the prototype of every possible element type instead of the `_` type.

Comment: do I? how does jQuery achieve this?

Comment: @wije: jQuery methods return a jQuery object, not an element.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>The constructor function needs to return itself (`return this;`). Currently it returns a DOM object, or `undefined` if no string is passed.</strike>

Try this:

```
function _(e) {
  if (!(this instanceof _)){
    return new _(e);
  }

  if (typeof e == 'string') {
    if (e.charAt(0) == '#') {
      this.el = document.getElementById(e.slice(1));
    } else if (e.charAt(0) == '.') {
      var c = document.getElementsByClassName(e.slice(1));
      this.el = (c.length==1)?c[0]:c;
    } else {
      var t = document.getElementsByTagName(e);
      this.el = (t.length==1)?t[0]:t;
    }
    return this;
  } else {
    console.log('Error. Not a valid string in _.');
    throw e + ' is not a valid string';
  }

}

_.prototype.hide = function() {
  console.log(this);
}
```

You can invoke the constructor like so:

```
e = _('#myDiv');
e.hide();
```

Comment: As the function is used as a plain function, not a constructor, `this` will be the global scope, i.e. `window`.

Comment: My previous answer was poor. I've had another go.

Comment: You can call the constructor directly `_('myDivID')` and it'll return a instance of `_`, which I think is what you want. Much nicer than having to invoke it thus: `el = new _('myDivID');`

Comment: thanks, that works. except it seems I have to call `_('#myDiv').el` not `_('#myDiv')` to get the div.

Comment: Yes, you're write. I see that your code is sensitive to tag names, classes and IDs. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score -2):

Try to define your function like this:

```
var _ = function (e) { };
```

**EDIT**
And yes don't forget to return `this` of course.